# Voh value not provided

Tags: digital-logic, logic-level

I have this [EEPROM](https://www.onsemi.com/pub/Collateral/CAT24C01-D.PDF) IC where I want to check the logic level compatibility with another IC.

But here Voh value is not given. I have observed this in my other IC also.
Why is the Voh value not provided? What shall I take as Voh?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This device uses an I2C interface so the SDA output is *open-collector* (or *open-drain*). They can only sink current to drive the SDA pin low; they cannot drive the pin high. So there is no specification for Voh or Ioh.

The SDA line is pulled high by an external pull-up resistor that you must add to the circuit. The value of Voh for SDA is determined by the value of the pull-up resistor and by sum of the leakage currents through all of the devices connected to the SDA signal.

Comment: thank you for the answer

Comment: Might be worth mentioning that you should pull the EEPROM voltage up to the Vcc of the EEEPROM and whatever else is connected to the I2C bus. If there are multiple Vcc voltages you should (generally) use a voltage translator between groups of devices with different Vcc voltages.